# Nested html tabs and playa fields please help

Tags: templates, playa, template-scripting, nesting

I now want to create a second set of pill tabs  based on a playa list called up  within the first channel entry (called "nwt_2cd_order_location") I am using Zurb Foundation's mark up for responsive design and it worked on flat pages.

The child in a playa list would be (called "3rd_order_under") and from that list i want to add content from that child. This all works pretty good until the user chooses a different selection under the first set of tabs (nwt_2cd_order_location).  It does not update the second set correctly (3rd_order_under).

If thats not enough, once that works i would like to add another playa list (no tabs this time fortunately) in the content derived from a playa list inside (3rd_order_under) called {4th_order_under_3rd_order}. Can you call up a playa list three tier deep?

So if any one here has any suggestions I sure would appreciate it.

Thanks
Eric

The page

http://niwot.colorado.edu/index.php/location

My simplified code:

<!-- PILL TABS -->

<div class="row">

```
<div class="twelve columns" style="padding-top:20px;"&#62;
  <dl class="tabs pill"&#62;
    {exp:channel:entries channel="nwt_2cd_order_location" limit="10" sort="asc"}
       <dd style="padding:5px;" {if count == '1'}class="active"{/if}> <a href="#pillTab{url_title}">{title}&#60;/a&#62;</dd>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
 </dl>

  <ul class="pill tabs-content contained">
          {exp:channel:entries channel="nwt_2cd_order_location" limit="10" sort="asc"}
       <li {if count == '1'}class="active"{/if} id="pillTab{url_title}Tab">
            <!-- li class="active" id="pillTab{url_title}" -->
            <div class="row">                              
                   <!-- MAP BOX -->       
               <div class="twelve columns" style="float:right;"> 
                  {summary}
               </div>

            {if 3rd_order_under}
            <p><strong>Locations within {title}</strong></p>
            {/if}      
         </div>        

      <dl class="tabs pill">
           {exp:playa:children field="3rd_order_under" limit="25" sort="asc"}
               <dd style="padding:5px;" {if count == '1'}class="active"{/if}><a href="#pillTab{url_title}">{title}</a>
               </dd>
          {/exp:playa:children}
      </dl>
```

<!-- CONTENT FOR 3rd ORDER pill tabs within pill tabs -->

```
    <ul class="pill tabs-content contained">
     {exp:playa:children field="3rd_order_under" limit="25" sort="asc"}
       <li {if count == '1'}class="active"{/if} id="pillTab{url_title}Tab">
            <div class="row">                                     
               <div class="twelve columns" style="float:right;"> 
                   {summary_3rd_order}<br />

                   {!-- nothing I've done here works
                   exp:playa:siblings entry_id="{4th_order_under_3rd_order}" parent_id="3rd_order_under"}
                   {4th_order_under_3rd_order}
                   {/exp:playa:siblings}
                   --}
               </div>
            </div>
         </li>
       {/exp:playa:children}
       {/exp:channel:entries}     
      </ul>   
    </li>    
  </ul>
```

the additional tab selections just stack on top each other instead of replacing the previous selection.

Comment: First and foremost, there's an error on your page because jQuery is not defined: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined. You either did not include it, or included it too late in the page.

Comment: You did include jQuery after 'foundation.tabs.js', make sure to include jQuery first!

Comment: Thanks- I moved jQueries around a bit. Still looking to solve problem however. That does not seem to be the problem or I did it incorrectly. Again thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You have still included your JavaScript in the wrong order, jQuery should come first.

How it is now:

```
<!-- More Foundation pannel -->
<script src="http://niwot.colorado.edu/eejavascripts/jquery.foundation.tabs.js"></script
<!-- END More Foundation pannel -->
<script src="http://niwot.colorado.edu/eejavascripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://niwot.colorado.edu/eejavascripts/foundation.min.js"></script>
```

How it must be:

```
<script src="http://niwot.colorado.edu/eejavascripts/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- More Foundation pannel -->
<script src="http://niwot.colorado.edu/eejavascripts/jquery.foundation.tabs.js"></script
<!-- END More Foundation pannel -->
<script src="http://niwot.colorado.edu/eejavascripts/foundation.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi @Joan, Based on your comment I had made a change very similar to this. It did not solve initial problem. However moving the closing children tag did. Closing the code block with              {/exp:playa:children} 
            </ul>   
          </li> 
             {/exp:channel:entries}    
        </ul>         
   </div>
</div>  working with var_prefix to try to fix the second problem.

Comment: Hi Eric, good to hear you solved it. I also see in your code that at
{!-- nothing I've done here works
exp:playa:siblings
You forgot the opening curly bracket. {